# Outputting mysql database rows from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I prevent this query not duplicate results like this:

My query is as follows:

```
 SELECT A.c_comp_name, A.i_id_user, B.c_name, C.c_map_name, D.c_temp_name
 FROM dc_cnf_costumer AS A, dc_cnf_page AS B, dc_cnf_map AS C, dc_cnf_renderer AS D
```

OUTPUT:

```
c_comp_name      i_id_user     c_name     c_map_name       c_temp_name
comp_1           4             Home       /map1/           template.php
comp_2           4             Home       /map1/           template_two.php
comp_1           4             Home       /map1/           template.php
comp_2           4             Home       /map1/           template_two.php
comp_1           4             Home       /map1/           template.php
comp_2           4             Home       /map1/           template_two.php
comp_1           4             Home       /map1/           template.php
comp_2           4             Home       /map1/           template_two.php
```

Comment: well you need something to relate rows from each table together. Show your table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` will not work on this case since NO two rows are the same.

The reason why you have duplicated values is because the **query produces cartesian product from 3 tables**. You should have provided a condition on which where the tables should be linked. Ex,

```
SELECT A.c_comp_name, A.i_id_user, B.c_name, C.c_map_name, D.c_temp_name
FROM dc_cnf_costumer AS A 
     INNER JOIN  dc_cnf_page AS B
         ON ....
     INNER JOIN dc_cnf_map AS C 
         ON ....
     INNER JOIN dc_cnf_renderer AS D
         ON ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add join conditions to your query - at present you are getting a cartesian join between all the rows on each table.

Comment: Please can the downvoter leave a comment explaining the downvote, so that the offered answer may be improved?

Answer (score 0):

1) add the word `distinct` after the word `select`

or

2) join your tables so the duplicates don't arise in the fist place

Answer (score 0):

either group by something unique or I suspect something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_comp_name .....
```

May work better for you.
Failing that a `GROUP BY i_id_user`  could also work